# Eclipse cannot detect my error code locations in web.xml, and security constraint is not blocking access to my .xhtml files

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, web.xml

I have a few problems with my web.xml. I am using Eclipse Indigo for development, and it is not detecting the .jsf files defined as the error code locations. My default suffix is .xhtml and I am using servlet mapping on url pattern *.jsf. However, other .jsf files defined in web.xml can be detected just fine. Due to this, the server is giving me 500 error when it should be 403 or 404 error.

Also, the security constraint I am using is not blocking access to the .xhtml files. When I navigate to the .xhtml files by the URL, I am presented with a blank screen and I can view the source codes through the browser. I expect the correct behaviour to be getting a 403 error.

Below is part of my web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/faces/index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/exceptionError.jsf</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/exceptionError.jsf</location>
</error-page>    

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restrict XHTML Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Indigo Juno Kepler,  Mars…  please upgrade Eclipse

Comment: To exclude the obvious, did you properly clean, rebuild, redeploy and restart the whole thing before testing?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned, rebuilt, redeployed and restarted the whole thing.